# Docker build fail

Tags: docker

My docker build command fails with the message:

```
Step 3/23 : RUN apt-get install   vim -yqq   cron -yqq   python-software-properties -yqq   supervisor -yqq  python-dev -yqq   python -yqq   python3-dev -yqq   python-distribute -yqq   python-pip -yqq   python-numpy -yqq   libjpeg8-dev -yqq   libfreetype6-dev -yqq   libxft-dev -yqq   curl -yqq   unzip -yqq
 ---> Running in 38d814924eaa
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_0.90ubuntu0.5_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install   vim -yqq   cron -yqq   python-software-properties -yqq   supervisor -yqq  python-dev -yqq   python -yqq   python3-dev -yqq   python-distribute -yqq   python-pip -yqq   python-numpy -yqq   libjpeg8-dev -yqq   libfreetype6-dev -yqq   libxft-dev -yqq   curl -yqq   unzip -yqq' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

My Dockerfile is (the relevant portion)

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install \
  vim -yqq \
  cron -yqq \
  software-properties-common -yqq \
  python-software-properties -yqq \
  supervisor -yqq\
  python-dev -yqq \
  python -yqq \
  python3-dev -yqq \
  python-distribute -yqq \
  python-pip -yqq \
  python-numpy -yqq \
  libjpeg8-dev -yqq \
  libfreetype6-dev -yqq \
  libxft-dev -yqq \
  curl -yqq \
  unzip -yqq
```

It was working perfectly fine last week but today I am getting the aforementioned error message. What is happening here?

Comment: why `-yqq` so many times?

Comment: This dockerfile was created by someone else and I wanted to modify it as little as possible, the `-yqq` was there when I started working on it, that cant be why it is failing though, right?

Comment: Are you manipulating apt.sources before apt-get?

Comment: It had been working fine earlier, dont know why its acting up now. I am not manipulating the sources, no. Running with no cache now.

Comment: well, the no-cache fixed it! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

build the image with

`--no-cache=true` option

to fix it

Comment: not for me - cache has no effect.